# Executing javascript functions on click difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have a javascript function that creates separate buttons, which I can then click to execute a different js function.  I have a different parameter for each of the created buttons for the js function.

This version of the function works.  It creates a new button with the onclick valChange function with parameter "addr2".  I want the "addr2" to be a string I can change as needed though, like how I have it in the second version.

the html is just the div that the function is meant to put the new divs into.
Both versions will create a new button inside the testbox div. Version 1's button works and will execute the alert valchange function on click.  Version 2's button does not execute the function.  How can I get version 2 to work and why does it not work currently?

```
<div id="testbox">

</div>
```

version 1, works

```
function dostuff()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<input type="button"onclick="valChange(`box1`)">;
    newDiv.innerHTML = html;
    $('#testbox').append(html);
}
```

version 2, doesn't work

```
function dostuff()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var i = "box1";
    var html = '<input type="button" onclick="valChange(i)">';
    newDiv.innerHTML = html;
    $('#testbox').append(html);
}
```

Shows an alert if the button actually works.

```
function valChange (divID)
{
    alert("it worked" + divID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some quotes there!
Currently on click JS expects a variable `box1` instead of a String (which is what you want)

```js
function dostuff() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var i = "box1";
  var html = '<input type="button" onclick="valChange(\''+ i +'\')">';
  newDiv.innerHTML = html;
  $('#testbox').append(html);
}

function valChange (divID) {
  alert("it worked" + divID);
} 

dostuff();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testbox"></div>
```

Another way to do it in jQuery is:

```js
function dostuff() {
  
  $inp = $("<input/>", {
    type : "button",
    value : "CLICK ME",
    click : valChange
  });
  
  $("<div/>", {
    append : $inp,
    appendTo : "#testbox"
  });

}

function valChange() {
  alert("My value is: " + this.value);
} 

dostuff();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

var i  is not used properly.

```
 function dostuff()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var i = "box1";
    var html = '<input type="button" onclick="valChange(\''+i+'\')">';
    newDiv.innerHTML = html;
    $('#testbox').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second version, it is seeing i as a string.  This should work:

```
function dostuff()
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var i = "box1";
        var html = '<input type="button" onclick="valChange(\'' + i + '\')">';
        newDiv.innerHTML = html;
        $('#testbox').append(html);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you epascarello. fixed it.